# How can I find my Bitcoin address on Airbitz?

Tags: wallet, e-wallet, airbitz

I'm new to Bitcoin. I'm using Airbitz on my phone and I need to find my wallet address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click in the top left that brings up the menu, select "Request". You will then be shown a screen with a QR code, your bitcoin address is below that QR.